# How can i update the already exsistant array that is outputed in the textArea with info given by the user?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I have 2 seperate arrays declared, where the corresponding index of each array is "information" about a person.

```
var alderArr: Array = [45, 34, 18, 12, 27];
var navnArr: Array = ["N. Linjesæter", "P. Kurverud", "O. Sirkelstad", "J. Rektangelsen", "M. Ellipsen"];
```

Then i also have 2 different input fields where the user can input information that will get added to the array when the button `btnLeggTill` is pressed. And the arrays seem to update based on the `trace(alderArr + "\n" + navnArr)`

```
btnLeggTil.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, leggTil);
function leggTil(evt:MouseEvent) {

    var nyttNavn: String = txtNavn.text;
    var nyAlder: int = int(txtAlder.text);
    //trace(nyttNavn + nyAlder);                            Debug
    alderArr.push(nyAlder);
    navnArr.push(nyttNavn);
    trace(alderArr + "\n" + navnArr);                                   
}//leggTil()

for (var i:int = 0; i < alderArr.length; i++) {

    textArea.text += navnArr[i] + ", Alder: " + alderArr[i] + "\n";
}//for
```

But the information does not seem to update in the textArea. This is basically what I want to accomplish. I want to make it so that when the user inputs new information and new things are added in the array, the textArea will also be updated so it displays this information to the user.

Comment: As you've already said, you have to update the text area when updating your arrays by putting your `for` loop inside the `leggTil()` function, of course, don't forget to reset your text area before updating it using : `textArea.text = '';` ...

Comment: @akmozo yeah, thanks. Was just a bit unsure how I would proceed with doing it, tried many different varities to try get it working, but overlooking the simple way as mentioned. Thanks again :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have 2 seperate arrays declared

While it certainly gets the job done, it's far from ideal. Splitting data that belongs together over several data structures means that you have to keep both arrays in sync.

A better way to model your data is to create a class for it. It's not too difficult, an obvious name would be `Person`. According to your code, a person has two properties: `age` and `name`. Save the following into a file named `Person.as` to get started.

```
package
{
    public class Person
    {
        private var name:String;
        private var age:int;
        
        public function Person(name:String, age:int)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }
    }
}
```

The advantages are that you can perform all kinds of sanity checks (on the given parameters and that you can add all kinds of functionality to it.

Speaking of functionality, add a `toString()` method, which returns a `String` representation of the object.

```
package
{
    public class Person
    {
        private var name:String;
        private var age:int;
        
        public function Person(name:String, age:int)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }
        
        public function toString():String
        {
            return name + ", Alder: " + age;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use that class to create objects, which can be passed to `trace()` to output them as a `String` according to the above function:

```
var person:Person = new Person("Jack", 35);

trace(person);   //Jack, Alder: 35
```

Now you could have a *single* `Array` of `Person` objects. That's much more intuitive. But there's a problem with `Array`...

> But the information does not seem to update in the textArea

That's true. The `TextArea` is a rather simple component. Just to be clear here, we are talking about Flash's [`fl.controls.TextArea`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/TextArea.html).

It's more or less just a `TextField`. It has no way of asking an array if it was updated (an element added, for example) and an `Array` has no way of telling anybody that it was updated.

The problem is usually solved by having something other than `Array`, which can tell if it just got changed. One class capable of doing that is `DataProvider`, specifically [`fl.data.DataProvider`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/data/DataProvider.html).

Instead of storing `Person` objects in an `Array`, you store them in a `DataProvider` on your main timeline:

```
var people:DataProvider = new DataProvider();

people.addItem(new Person("Jack", 35));
people.addItem(new Person("Jane", 20));
people.addItem(new Person("Charlie", 25));

for (var i:int = 0; i < people.length; ++i)
{
    trace(people.getItemAt(i));
}
```

This adds some dummy data and uses a `for` loop to `trace()` all items.
To join the elements to a string more easily, you can also get an `Array` representation from the `DataProvider` and call its `join()` method:

```
var people:DataProvider = new DataProvider();

people.addItem(new Person("Jack", 35));
people.addItem(new Person("Jane", 20));
people.addItem(new Person("Charlie", 25));

trace(people.toArray().join("\n"));
```

To inform others about the change of data, the `DataProvider` dispatches a `fl.events.DataChangeEvent` of type `DATA_CHANGE`. Add a listener for that event to update the `TextArea` accordingly:

```
var people:DataProvider = new DataProvider();

people.addEventListener(DataChangeEvent.DATA_CHANGE, onDataChange);

function onDataChange(e:DataChangeEvent):void
{
    textArea.text = people.toArray().join("\n");
}

people.addItem(new Person("Jack", 35));
people.addItem(new Person("Jane", 20));
people.addItem(new Person("Charlie", 25));
```

Whenever you add (or remove) something from the `DataProvider`, the event fires and `textArea` is updated. In your code, this could look like this:

```
var people:DataProvider = new DataProvider();
people.addEventListener(DataChangeEvent.DATA_CHANGE, onPeopleDataChanged);

function onPeopleDataChanged(e:DataChangeEvent):void
{
    textArea.text = people.toArray().join("\n");
}

addPersonButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addPerson);
function addPerson(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    people.addItem(new Person(nameInput.text, int(ageInput.text)));
}
```

I changed your variable names. **ALWAYS** use English identifiers in your programming. It's a major pain to read your code without knowing what a *leggTil* is. If you ask people on the internet for help, use English.
If I first have to come up with the elvish word for friend before understanding your code, chances are I'll be eaten by a giant octopus before being able to help you. It is in your own interest to make your code as easy to digest as possible.

Also note that I removed the local variables. There's no real need for them and they only bloat the code. With functionality in the `Person` class, the code is really slim now. It almost reads like human lanugage: "*add an item to people which is a new person with given name and age*"

---

The `DataProvider` works even better with other classes than `TextArea`.
In my answer, I only demonstrate how to make the `Array` smarter. But there are other things similar to `TextArea` that are smarter, too. Some components can be passed a `DataProvider` directly. They add the listener to themselves and wire up the functionality to update their text when the `DataProvider` changes. If you do not explicitly have to use`TextArea`, I recommend using `ComboBox`, `DataGrid`, `List` or `TileList` component. [Here's an article on how to make them work with a `DataProvider`](https://web.archive.org/web/20171019184046/http://help.adobe.com:80/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fce.html)

Comment: I looked a bit into DataProviders previously, but personally do not have that much experience using them. Relatively new to "coding" and actionscript and trying to get a hold of things. But this is definately something I will take a closer look into seeing how the code seems to be a lot more clear and logical this way. Appreciate the help.